# Sanitizing static freestanding nolibc programs?

Tags: c, low-level, address-sanitizer, sanitizer, freestanding

I'm developing a static freestanding nolibc/nostdlib program for Linux and would like to use the C compiler's memory, address and undefined behavior sanitizers to improve my code.

I couldn't get it to work when I tried it though:

```
clang -static -ffreestanding -nostdlib -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=undefined -g -o program program.c
```

This causes the compiler to emit instrumentation code that calls functions such as `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1@plt`. It compiles and links successfully but the program segfaults near those references when run. More specifically, in my memory allocator:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) up
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function lone_reallocate:
...
   0x00000000002116d0 <+160>:   bl      0x206470 <__ubsan_handle_pointer_overflow@plt>
=> 0x00000000002116d4 <+164>:   b       0x2116d8 <lone_reallocate+168>
   0x00000000002116d8 <+168>:   ldur    x8, [x29, #-72]
...
```

I assume these functions are missing due to the lack of libc support. When I tried to use the `-static-libsan` option, I got numerous undefined sybol errors:

```
error: undefined symbol: __aarch64_cas8_acq_rel
error: undefined symbol: pthread_self
error: undefined symbol: dl_iterate_phdr
error: undefined symbol: abort
...
```

How can I make this work? Do I have to implement those functions? If so, how? I couldn't find any documentation on this matter.

Can operating systems and kernels use these sanitizers? If they can, then whatever method they use would also be applicable to my use case.

Comment: Make separate builds for your project. One uses the sanitizers in a hosted program calling your functions compiled for a hosted environment. The other builds freestanding versions.

Comment: Consider the question from a different perspective for a moment.  What do you expect the instrumentation actually to *do* if it detects a memory-use issue or undefined behavior?  There are no standard I/O functions in a freestanding environment, and not even a standard means to terminate execution.  How is the instrumentation going to tell you about what it discovered?

Comment: Yes, you could conceivably implement your own versions of all the functions the instrumentation requires, but that would be a major project of its own.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have full access to Linux system calls, I can use `write` and `exit`. I have also written my own I/O functions. I suppose I can use these to report errors and kill the program.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira, it's an odd freestanding program that can rely on system calls.  There not being an OS underneath is the point of a freestanding implementation.  But even if in fact you have a Linux kernel underneath, you should not expect the syscall wrapper functions to be available to your freestanding code, and you cannot reasonably expect the sanitizer instrumentation to make syscalls directly.  Even `exit()` is an implementation-defined extension in a freestanding implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's freestanding in the sense that it's using the freestanding C dialect as opposed to hosted C. I'm targeting the Linux system call ABI directly, wrote the wrappers myself, [even blogged about it](https://www.matheusmoreira.com/articles/linux-system-calls). I'm not sure why it would be unsafe to use system calls, they're stateless and safe to use even in signal handlers.

Comment: I didn't say it was unsafe to use system calls if they are in fact available to you.  I said that a C program running on a freestanding implementation ordinarily does not have any system calls available to draw on, except to the extent that it implements them itself.  And I said that you can neither expect the sanitizer tooling to make direct system calls, nor to have any syscall wrapper functions available to it other than those you provide yourself.

Comment: A quick workaround is to `-ldl -lpthread -lgcc` and supply an `abort(3)` implementation yourself, but I doubt if that makes the program still qualify as freestanding. Alternative is to reimplement the functions, but the reliance on libdl and pthreads for them can make it a major hassle.